# How to properly leave a Critical Section?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, synchronization

I have the following C++ code where I make use of the [Critical Section object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

// code that may throw an exception

LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

How can I ensure that the `LeaveCriticalSection` function is called even if an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just write a guard utilizing the destructor for clean up:

```
struct Guard {
  CriticalSection& cs;
  Guard(CriticalSection& cs)
  : cs(cs)
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(cs);
  }
  ~Guard() {
    LeaveCriticalSection(cs);
  }
  Guard(const Guard&) = delete;  
  Guard& operator = (const Guard&) = delete;
};
```

Usage:

```
void f() {
   Guard guard(cs);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization) idiom:

```
struct GuardCS {
    GuardCS(CRITICAL_SECTION& p_cs) : cs(p_cs){
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    }
    ~GuardCS() {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    }
private:
    // Protect against copying, remove: =delete on pre c++11 compilers
    GuardCS(GuardCS const &) = delete;
    GuardCS& operator =(GuardCS const &) = delete;
    CRITICAL_SECTION& cs;
};
```

If you are using MFC by any chance there are classes that abstract such stuff: [is Ccriticalsection usable in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366105/is-ccriticalsection-usable-in-production)

Comment: If I could make one minor suggestion, and perhaps it is still wise to omit it simply for the sake of a simpler example to build upon, it might be healthy to make GuardCS noncopyable.

Answer (score 4):

> *"How can I ensure that the LeaveCriticalSection function is called even if an exception is thrown?"*

You can write a small helper class like this:

```
 class CsLocker {
 public:
     CsLocker(CriticalSection& cs)
     : cs_(cs) {
         EnterCriticalSection(&cs_);
     }
     ~CsLocker() {
          LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
     }
     CsLocker(const CsLocker&) = delete;
     CsLocker& operator=(const CsLocker&) = delete;
 private:
     CriticalSection& cs_;
 };
```

That will guarantee that the critical section is unlocked whenever (and why ever) the scope is left.

Comment: This is dangerous. If somebody accidentally copies the `CsLocker`, you're hosed.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit You're right, I have fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not to use WinAPI critical sections. You can get the same by using [std::mutex](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex). When you use it you also can use [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) wrapper for auto unlocking mutex ([std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) ).

UPDATE: one difference between critical section and mutex that you can lock critical section multiple times on one thread but this is not true for simple std::mutex. If you need recursive behaviour of locking use [std::recursive_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex) `std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex>`

UPDATE 2: Detailed difference between critical sections and mutexes are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section), performance comparison is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997473/stdmutex-performance-compared-to-win32-critical-section).

Reasons: It is better to use standard-defined mechanism whenever you can. If you use platform-specific thing - wrap it around. So if you afraid for performance - create Critical section class with lock/unlock methods (to meet [BasicLocakable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable) concept requirements) and use `std::lock_guard<MyCriticalSection>`.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use the WinAPI critical sections?

Comment: @Nick Because your code won't be portable to other systems.

Comment: You limit your code to execute on Windows-only systems without any specific reasons.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My code has not to be portable, anyway +1 for the advise.

Comment: There are so many benefits to using the standard tools. "I don't need portability" is not a good enough excuse to arbitrarily eschew them.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Do I have the benefit of speed by using std objects instead of WinAPI critical sections?

Comment: @Nick: What makes you think the standard objects are not implemented using WinAPI critical sections, on a Windows toolchain? How else would they be implemented? The _whole point_ of C++ is that it's an abstraction.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit I never said that, anyway there are so many syncrhonization objects in Windows, as for example mutex that are quite slower with respect to cirtical sections. I do not know how std::mutex is implemented, but if it does not use critical section it will be slower. Therefore, as I said, I don't need portability, I need speed first of all.

Comment: I do not like the statement 'I suggest you not to use WinAPI critical sections.' without reasoning. Especially, what are the differences beteween  a CriticalSection and std::mutex or std::std::recursive_mutex ?

Comment: @Nick Question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997473/stdmutex-performance-compared-to-win32-critical-section

Comment: @DieterLücking: Unless the OP is already aware of such a difference and _requires_ to make use of it, that is also an insufficient reason to eschew standard types. _Use them until you can't._

Comment: I like the idea to implement a wrapper implementing the BasicLockable concept +1.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct about using RAII objects but I feel it is worth pointing out an easy way to do this with [`Boost.ScopeExit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

```
#include <boost/scope_exit.hpp>
...
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&cs) {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
} BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
// code that may throw an exception
```